# Do we need multiple shortcodes to handle multiple brands and multiple programs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, unsubscribe, sharing-keywords

Tried my best utilzing online resources to learn and understand but couldn't get some definitive approach to proceed further.

Can someone please shed some advice on this scenario ot decide on one or multiple shortcodes?

1. Have Brand A and Brand B - both wants to share a shortcode but both have different customer base and just that both businessess are under one parent organization / business.
2. Both A and B wants to run multiple SMS programs as well. Two SMS programs by Brand A can happen and / or Two SMS programs by Brand B will happen at same time.

Considering the above scenario, not sure how the STOP and HELP keywords can be implemented if the content inside these have to be different.

1. HELP - For example, phone / email inside HELP keyword setup has to be different.How to set multiple HELP so anyone from Brand A send HELP command recieves correct info and same way for Brand B. Seems this is setup at parent level business unit as part of the  shortcode setup and approval so how to get it inside each business unit.
2. STOP - As this is attached to a shortcode and not to a program keyword (like Join / enroll / marketing) then how one can just optout from one SMS program but still recieve message from other program. Sounds like STOP <ProgramName#> is not a possibility.

Also, came across this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_es_subscribers_on_publication_list.htm&type=5) but cannot understand as when I tried to verify, "STOP MARKETING" or "STOP DEALS"(example - program name is Marketing / Deals for Brand A), it just takes the first word STOP and just optouts globally as per this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_moc_stop_keywords.htm&type=5) . Also, this [stackExchange url](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34780/unsubscribe-from-sms-keyword-through-api) talks about STOP keyword at BU level and also suggests setting up something like custom one in a BU like "STOP1". Is that correct as I couldn't get it to work, not sure what is wrong with the setup?

Used QueueMO api call to opt in from a webform but the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_es_subscribers_on_publication_list.htm&type=5) is also saying that Optout is possible using publicaiton lists but couldn't find any resources on this. Is that even a possiblity for USA region?

Is there an option to handle Optouts via cloud page (like email studio preference center for publication lists)? If yes, can someone please suggest how this can be done and is it a good practice to take users to a page to do this? If they still send STOP command, then that cannot be avoided which is required and fine.

Hope to receive some clarifications to decide on next steps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: a stop MO will opt the customer out of all keywords for the shortcode, you can not opt out of a keyword individually. You could use api to manage optin/optout of a keyword. But if a subscriber is optedin to any keyword they are eligible to receive text messages from that short code, so you would need to ensure you are filtering on keyword status before any send

Comment: @EazyE thnaks for the reply, cna you please point me to any api document on this optout of a keyword funcitonality. I couldn't find any resource in regards to that. Also, are you referring to MO in queue MO ?

Comment: It would be leveraging the contacts rest route

Comment: Hi @PJJD, I haven't come across this scenario. But see if my comment is making sense. Please ask your account executive, if you can use 2 Short codes or long codes to send each for one brand? If customer sends STOP it will get opted out for that particular short code. You can also go with the cloud page approach based.If they opt out for one particular brand then update the fields in salesforce and master data extension.Every time before you send a SMS try to check on the fields if its true then send. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @NaveenVM thanks. multiple shortcode for multiple Business/ Business units under 1 business will resolve the problem. But thinking how can the cloud page will help in this place. This is my thought process
1. a page where they can enter mobile number/pick checkboxes for multiple programs(keywords).
2. capture the above in a DE and then use columns in the mobile connect list that we have for each program/keyword as a filter to exclude the numbers.
contd..

Comment: 3.But now trying to find some option (api/ampscript) through which I can frequently take the numbers from that DE and then change status from "Opted in" to "Not Opted in" for a specific program/keyword and not from shortcode.
I am almost good with step 1 and 2. Trying to find some direction for step 3. Irrespective of this approach, if anyone still send STOP, it will opt them out from shortcode and we cannot avoid that/stop it.

Comment: @PJJD Thanks for explaining. You are expecting something like a publication list based upon keyword which is not an OOTB in Mobile connect. But what you can do that is when customer opt out for a particular keyword via cloud page. Then you can add a record in data extension. For each keyword different data extension. Then you can exclude these data extensions using sql query. For list, you can add this to a contact builder and exclude these data extensions via manager filter. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @NaveenVM, thanks again, can you please explain more details on this suggestion? . 
Then you can exclude these data extensions using sql query. 
Sql query in where?

For list, you can add this to a contact builder and exclude these data extensions via manager filter. Let me know if this helps.
I am not sure how this works, if you cna please share any link to read, it will help. 

Also, tryng  to utilize _mobilesubscription if we can change optin status to "not opted in" . not sure yet.

Comment: @PJJD what i meant is that, lets say you send an outbound SMS via JB to ask subscriber to optin via keyword call 'AGREE'. Once the customer has typed 'AGREE' then using ampscript in text response msg add them into a keyword data extension called 'Agree data extension'. Lets say customer has un-subscribed for that particular keyword via cloud page. In cloud page amp script you would need to add another record in different data extension called 'un-sub Agree data extension'. Whenever you send a sms next time you do a SQL query exclude those contacts present in 'un-sub Agree data extension'.

Comment: Let me know if this helps